# Android MediaPlayer stops after playing the first time

Tags: android, listener, media-player, android-mediaplayer, file-descriptor

//This is the edited code that works:

I have been trying to find different ways to fix it, but it looks like I have to ask for help.

The media player plays the file the first time and never again.
This is the code:

```
btn_default_acc = (ImageButton) layout.findViewById(R.id.btn_df_acc);
        btn_default_acc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {if(sentencePlayer==null){
                        sentencePlayer  = new MediaPlayer();
                    }sentencePlayer.reset();
                    sentencePlayer.setDataSource(fd.getFileDescriptor(), fd.getStartOffset(), fd.getLength());
                    sentencePlayer.prepare();
                    sentencePlayer.start();

                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        sentencePlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer sentencePlayer) {
                sentencePlayer.stop();


            }
        });
```

and the logcat:
`01-11 13:28:36.744 9044-9044/com.testapp.imre.testapp W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalStateException
01-11 13:28:36.744 9044-9044/com.testapp.imre.testapp W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaPlayer._setDataSource(Native Method)
01-11 13:28:36.744 9044-9044/com.testapp.imre.testapp W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1254)
01-11 13:28:36.744 9044-9044/com.testapp.imre.testapp W/System.err:     at com.testapp.imre.testapp.Lesson1Reading$11.onClick(Lesson1Reading.java:1134)
01-11 13:28:36.744 9044-9044/com.testapp.imre.testapp W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5156)
01-11 13:28:36.744 9044-9044/com.testapp.imre.testapp W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20755)
01-11 13:28:36.744 9044-9044/com.testapp.imre.testapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
01-11 13:28:36.744 9044-9044/com.testapp.imre.testapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-11 13:28:36.744 9044-9044/com.testapp.imre.testapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
01-11 13:28:36.744 9044-9044/com.testapp.imre.testapp W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
01-11 13:28:36.744 9044-9044/com.testapp.imre.testapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-11 13:28:36.744 9044-9044/com.testapp.imre.testapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
01-11 13:28:36.744 9044-9044/com.testapp.imre.testapp W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
01-11 13:28:36.744 9044-9044/com.testapp.imre.testapp W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)`

I also modified the method that closes the screen:

`private View.OnClickListener close_popup_screen_listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (sentencePlayer != null){
                sentencePlayer.stop();
            }
            popUpScreen.dismiss();
            try {
                fd.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            stopMediaRecorder();
        }
    };`

Comment: After you `release()` a `MediaPlayer` instance, it is no longer usable. Also, if you call `reset()` (but not `release()`), you have to re-initialize it before using it again.

Comment: I have modified the code above and I am still getting an error: java.lang.SecurityException at android.media.MediaPlayer._prepare(Native Method)

Comment: You're getting that error because you've closed the `FileDescriptor`.

Comment: Also, if you're going to instantiate a new `MediaPlayer` like you are now, you should `release()` the old one.

Comment: I have modified the onClick method a bit (as per above) and have moved fd.close(); to the method that closes the window. I have even removed the sentenceplayer.release(); line from the onCompletionListener. Now it says: java.lang.IllegalStateException at android.media.MediaPlayer._setDataSource(Native Method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add sentencePlayer.reset();

Before setDataSource

Comment: The combination of the three answers has worked. I will give the credit to you. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please remove below two lines ?

```
sentencePlayer.reset();
sentencePlayer.release();
```

Your method should looks like below:

```
    sentencePlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer sentencePlayer) {
            sentencePlayer.stop();
        }
    });
```

**Edit 1**:

Remove below line:

```
sentencePlayer.reset();
```

Add below line:

```
if(sentencePlayer==null){
 sentencePlayer  = new MediaPlayer();
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I have modified the code above and am getting the following: java.lang.SecurityException at android.media.MediaPlayer._prepare(Native Method)

Comment: @Immy, Please check Edit 1.

Comment: Yes. I just tried it. java.lang.IllegalStateException  at android.media.MediaPlayer._setDataSource(Native Method)

Comment: Hi Hiren, the combination of the three answers has worked. Thank you very much for your help. I will accept the answer by @Leonardo G. Roese so he can get the points. Thanks again